# How do i remove Docker completely?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i installed docker follow this post
https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/getting-started-docker-vps/

```
sudo curl -sS https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

this leak seem unsafe, i wanted to remove everything with docker and reinstall again in other method.

after remove all and check with

```
find / -name '*docker*'
```

the log

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/docker0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/docker0
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/docker0
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh/docker0
/proc/1/task/1/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/1/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/2/task/2/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/2/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/3/task/3/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/3/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/84/task/84/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/84/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/92/task/92/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/92/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/96/task/96/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/96/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/114/task/114/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/114/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/127/task/127/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/127/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/133/task/133/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/133/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/134/task/134/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/134/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/151/task/151/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/151/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/368/task/368/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/368/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/371/task/371/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/371/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/372/task/372/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/372/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/373/task/373/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/373/task/376/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/373/task/390/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/373/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/386/task/386/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/386/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/393/task/393/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/393/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/404/task/404/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/404/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/407/task/407/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/407/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/408/task/408/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/408/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/416/task/416/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/416/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/448/task/448/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/448/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/572/task/572/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/572/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/574/task/574/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/574/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/2523/task/2523/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/2523/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/2526/task/2526/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/2526/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/3110/task/3110/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/3110/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/3111/task/3111/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/3111/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/3114/task/3114/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/proc/3114/net/dev_snmp6/docker0
/usr/bin/pm2-docker
/usr/libexec/docker
/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-docker
/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/systeminformation/lib/dockerSocket.js
/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/systeminformation/lib/docker.js
/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/@pm2/io/docker-compose.yml
/usr/lib/firewalld/services/docker-swarm.xml
/usr/lib/firewalld/services/docker-registry.xml
/sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0
/sys/class/net/docker0
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/docker-ce-stable
/var/lib/docker-engine
/var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/7/docker-ce-stable
/etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

how do i remove docker completely ? is this file inside my host are safe ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker Please refer this link. I hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Why do you think that executing code from a trustworthy, HTTPS-encrypted website is a security risk? You can incidentally just open that script in your browser and see if it did anything shady. Also, if it really *did* do something shady, your entire OS should be considered compromised and you'd need a full reinstall of that, at least, as the script could potentially have corrupted the kernel, a system service or literally anything else.

Comment: @Taschi well i am not sure cause i am new with the vps stuff, so i want to do it right, cause the post said it might be a treat. but i didt notice it was https, if that should be fine :D, thanks for point it out.

Comment: Well, HTTPS doesn't mean the site is trustworthy. But docker.com is trustworthy and HTTPS prevents third-party intervention. So, in this case you'll be fine. Just make sure from now on to check any shell scripts you download from the interweb before executing them.

Comment: @Taschi Understood :D, appreciate your advice. i will close the post ^^

Answer (score 0):

Quick summary of my comments so far, so you can accept it as an answer:

- You downloaded the script from a trustworthy source (docker.com) and via HTTPS so there is *extremely little* risk of your system being compromised.
- If your system was compromised, uninstalling docker would likely not solve the problem.

With those two caveats out of the way: The script you ran does a lot of magic to determine your operating system, and then delegates the actual installation to the appropriate package manager, meaning you can simply uninstall it through the usual package management tools of your Linux distribution.